# Running multiple Bitcoin nodes on same network

Tags: bitcoind

I want to run a **bitcoin node on two separate devices** (computer + dedicated hardware device) **on the same network** (and would like them to be externally accessible).  Specifically, I have a Casa Node with bitcoind, and I have a Mac with bitcoind. Both on my home network.

I've read it is critical that you forward port 8333 on your router to the IP address of the computer that is running your node, so I'm not sure what to do on the dedicated hardware device then.

I've seen you can add `port` and `rpcport` arguments to the bitcoin.conf file, but I'm can't figure out exactly how this setup will work on the same network with two different bitcoin nodes.

Any help by someone more expert (most people likely ha) than me would be appreciated, thanks!

`Bitcoin.conf` file

```
daemon=1
server=1
prune=750
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxx
```

Comment: Not a full answer, but if you want to expose your node to the internet (which isn't critical at all, it's your choice if you want to help strengthen other's connections; the node gives you the same security and benefit regardless of whether it is reachable), you can just make one of the two reachable, and use the 'addnode' option to connect your two nodes to each other.

Comment: Note you can do this with different node implementations. You might have your bitcoind connected to outbound/inbound peers, but add a permanent peer connection to your second Libbitcoin server, which is in your local network without any other connections configured. The Libbitcoin node will receive all “validated” resources from the Bitcoind, and its strong chain will reflect the venn intersection between Bitcoind and Libbitcoin Validation spaces (Useful, in the case of potential implementation bugs in either implementations)

Comment: @PieterWuille thanks for breaking the `addnode` option down for me, I hadn't even see that, but now I know about it and feel like I understand it enough from your response too. Awesome!

Comment: @JamesC. thats really interesting, had no idea!

Comment: Note that the 'addnode' command will only work if the added node has a fully synced chain (flag “NODE_NETWORK”).