# Running two nodes on the same network

Tags: nodes

[Running multiple Bitcoin nodes on same network](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/81505/running-multiple-bitcoin-nodes-on-same-network)
That post discussed it, but I need a little more help than that. I am not totally sure what to do with the config file and the add node.

Where can I get more detailed instructions. Thanks for the help. One node is a nodl the other is on a Windows PC

Comment: Please explain what you've done and the result you're getting.

Comment: so far nothing, I need to understand the necessary set up for the router if any. Is it just the config file for the nodes. I really pretty much "know nothing." I need easy instructions.  Also how to use Addnode. Thank you for your help.

Comment: check out https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Sample_Bitcoin.conf, specifically the section on addnode vs connect, I believe it still applies with the latest version of Bitcoin Core.